# How to show activity indicator in UICollectionView cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, activity-indicator

I'm trying to show activity indicator for every cell until the image for UICollectionView cell show up, but it only shown in the last cell.

[image: view]

My code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 160, height: 200))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 160, height: 200))

    cell.contentView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    containerView.backgroundColor = .magenta

    containerView.addSubview(imageView)

    guard imageArray.count == tempListLength && tempListLength > 0 else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activityIndicator.center = cell.contentView.center
        }
        return cell
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
    imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a single activity indicator which you reposition to various cells. Why would you expect to see multiple indicators?

Comment: @idmean How can i place activity indicator in every cell?

Comment: create activity indicator in your custom cell....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Activity indicator in your custom cell

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  private lazy var spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            commonInit()
        }

        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: coder)
            commonInit()
        }

        private func commonInit() {
             spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(spinner)

            spinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            spinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
         }
    }
```

Then in cellForItemAt method you just need to do is to start animate and stop animate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)

   cell.spinner.startAnimating() 
// OR
  cell.spinner.stopAnimating()

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my mistake was creating one activity indicator outside of cellForItemAt